# Query that finds objects with ALL association ids (Rails 4)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

BACKGROUND: Posts have many Communities through CommunityPosts. I understand the following query returns posts associated with ANY ONE of these community_ids.

```
Post.joins(:communities).where(communities: { id: [1,2,3] })
```

OBJECTIVE: I'd like to query for posts associated with ALL THREE community_ids in the array. Posts having communities 1, 2, and 3 as associations

EDIT: Please assume that length of the array is unknown. Used this array for explanation purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
ids=[...]
Post.joins(:communities).select(“count(communities.id) AS cnt”).where(id: ids).group(‘post.id’).having(cnt: ids.size)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ids = [1, 2, 3] # and etc
Post.joins(:communities).where("communities.id IN ?", ids)
```

Wish it helps .